# xml parsing using javascript returned from a webservice

Tags: javascript, xml

how to parse xml returned from a webservice.

```
<Locations>
  <Location>
    <Id>666</Id>
    <Latitude>38.5699</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-121.381</Longitude>
    <Address>3638 American River Dr</Address>
    <City>Sacramento</City>
    <Country>US</Country>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Id>665</Id>
    <Latitude>38.5699</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-121.381</Longitude>
    <Address>3638 American River Dr</Address>
    <City>Sacramento</City>
    <Country>US</Country>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Id>664</Id>
    <Latitude>38.5699</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-121.381</Longitude>
    <Address>3638 American River Dr</Address>
    <City>Sacramento</City>
    <Country>US</Country>
  </Location>
</Locations>
```

please help me that how can i get individually Id and other attributes?

Comment: this has been answered so many times....have you searched yet? SO MANY TIMES

Comment: man you can parse it using javascript or jquery Just search on it,
see this http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery look here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Otherwise just search on this site, there are plenty of examples
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+xml+javascript